# Signing of query string for authentication

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication

We are having troubles making our authentication for the REST Api robust.

We are generating our signed hash with the api key, timestamp etc. etc. as well as the request body or url query string. Everything sent in the body must always be JSON so thats no problem.
But signing the query string gives us a headache.

> All REST queries must be authenticated by signing the query parameters
>   sorted in lower-case, alphabetical order using the private credential
>   as the signing token. Signing should occur before URL encoding the
>   query string.

But what now with key[0]=somevalue&key[1]=someothervalue. How to order that?
The alternative is to always force JSON in the query string also, is that a viable solution?

someurl?{"somekey":"somevalue"}

*Edit*

The problem which got us to this point is the following: I (the client) send the request with ?a=value1&b=value2, and create the hash with this querystring. But we had failing requests because the server (Apache, PHP) sometimes received ?b=value2&a=value1. Hashing that gives a different result and so a failed auth.

Comment: Hmm, what's the actual problem? Parsing the query string? Ordering the resulting multi dimensional array?

Comment: What´s the goto solution here? How do other Apis deal with this? Is JSON in the URL a good thing? Thanks

Comment: Different APIs, different solutions. All the REST APIs I've been using that work with signing query strings (mostly OAuth based), do require signing them in a specific order. I've never seen a REST API that uses JSON for passing GET parameters, but ofcourse that doesn't mean anything, personally however I wouldn't do it that way, I'd stick with standard URIs using paths and/or query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow correctly, so you have an array containing the parameters called `$key`? 
And this needs to be alphabetically ordered?

I would do the following

```
sort($key);
$queryStr = '';
for($k = 0; $k < count($key); $k++)
{
      $queryStr .= 'key['.$k.']='.strtolower($key[$k]);
      if($k < count($key)-1)
             $queryStr .= '&';
}

$restURL = 'someurl?'.$queryStr;
```

Comment: Thanks, so you´d prefer such a custom sorting on both ends over json_encoding the whole thing to make sure all stays the same?

Comment: Based on "_All REST queries must be authenticated by signing the query parameters sorted in_ **lower-case, alphabetical order** _using the private credential as the signing token._" then yes. I don't understand what you mean by both ends. Do you have control of the server you're interacting with? Also what is the API you're using? I've never come across one which needs the query to be ordered.

Comment: Basically I have control over both the server too, yes. The Quote is from here: [link](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html)
Thats also how Amazon requires requests to the AWS Api to be. I updated the question with another clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We are authenticating through custom headers x-hash and x-time . There only ever is payload in the body or the query string. But the query string is used in GET requests to filter etc. So there can be ?product=32 or ?id[]=1&id[]=2. And that´s what appears to need ordering